# I am not getting the 'Profile' property in the code behind

Tags: asp.net

hai ,

I have added some profile properties to my web.config:

```
<profile automaticSaveEnabled ="true">
        <properties>
          <add name="NumVisits" type="System.Int32"/>
          <add name="UserName" type="System.String"/>
          <add name="Gender" type="bool"/>
          <add name="Birthday" type="System.DateTime"/>
         </properties> 
      </profile>
```

However when I try to access the property in a code behind it does not
exist. The following code does not work (says firstname is not a property):

Profile.Gender
And In the Asp.net Configuration 'Profile tab ' Is not showing.
I have rebuilt the solution. I am using VB.NET(3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to retrieve Profile properties value is like below.

object obj = HttpContext.Current.Profile["PropertyName"]; (C# code).

Comment: I have seen something like 'Profile.Gender' .